# Using angular variables inside controller depending on path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

i want to use the same controller fo two different tables..only difference is one variable..

```
if($location.path() == '/type_user')
{
    $scope.varName  = 'User';   
    $scope.pathTo   = '/users'; 
    $scope.objName  = 'users';

}else if($location.path() == '/type_user_params')
{
    $scope.varName = 'Param';
    $scope.pathTo  = '/params';
    $scope.objName = 'params';

}
```

and then use it in a function like so:

```
   $scope.objName.splice($scope.objName .indexOf(xxx),1);
```

or:

```
   $scope.objName.push($scope.inserted);
```

but i am getting

```
$scope.objName.push is not a function
```

Comment: What is the values of `$scope.objName`???\

Comment: is it splice or slice ? 
splice is used with array where as slice is used with string ?
I get error when I try to debug your code "TypeError: objName.splice is not a function"

Answer (score 3):

Thats because `$scope.objName` is a string  **doesn't** have the push method in it's prototype.

An array does have the push method on it's prototype ([Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)).

You can add you own implementation to a string by using code like this:

```
String.prototype.push = function(str)
{
    return this + str;
}

var a = 'abc';
var b = a.push('de');
console.log(b); // abcde
```

but it's **not** recommended.

Anyway it looks like you want something like this:

```
var last = $location.path().split('_').pop();
$scope.varName = last.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + last.substr(1);
$scope.pathTo  = '/' + last;
$scope.objName = last;
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use objName as an array then it should be `$scope.objName = [];`

then you can use the push and pop functions for the array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use resolve:

```
when(
url:'/type_user',
controller: MyController,
resolve: {
    varName  : 'User', 
    pathTo   : '/users', 
    objName  : 'users',
}
)

when(
url:'/type_user_params',
controller: MyController,
resolve: {
    varName  : 'Param', 
    pathTo   : '/params', 
    objName  : 'params',
}
)
```

Then you can inject them inside your controller:

```
function($scope, varName,pathTo,objName) { ... }
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

It is useful, also for getting ajax promises. All promises wil have to be executed before entering the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Push is a method on array.

`$scope.objName` is a string. So you get the error that you are getting.

**Word of caution**: the way that you have written code will soon land you in trouble. I am talking about if else part for constructing the variable.

Comment: please explain why. @Anand

Comment: due to if else part. The controller does not need to know about these differences, It just need to execute with given value. You should make it more generic. So that tomorrow you do not have to add another else part

Comment: Look at the answer written by @Beri. That's one possible way of reuse if the values changes depending upon the location